# Print the reverse of a string using recursion

Tags: c, string, pointers, recursion, reverse

I am trying to print a string in reverse using recursion. However, the program below does not work as expected. What is the cause?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char arr[]="rama";
    fun(arr);
}

int fun(char *p)
{
    static int i=0;
    
    if((p[i]) == '\0')
       return;
    else
    {
        i++;
        fun(p[i]);
        printf("%c", p[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `static` variables in recursion is kind of "cheating". The task can be accomplished with pure recursion

Comment: why adding static is cheating ?

Comment: Because it is the same as global. It is defeating the whole idea of recursion.

Comment: @Ravi static variable here is the global variable, and global state is quite bad: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil

Comment: Some other things 1) you define `fun` to return an `int`, but never do you actually do that or try to capture a return value. 2) `fun` accepts a `char*` argument, but your recursive call passes it a `char`.

Comment: Ravi, Save your valuable time.  Enable all compiler warnings to warn why `fun(p[i]);` is bad.

Comment: i got this warning but could not understand why?    warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fun’ makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: @yano   I though  char *p  and  char p[i] are same in one sense   as  *(p+i) === p[i] hence i passed   fun(p[i])  though it is declared  fun(char *p)    is my assumption wrong?

Comment: @Eugene   though it is cheating and should be avoided , but it should work ...right? What is wrong other than using static?

Comment: If you prefer the array syntax you have to add a second argument to your function.

Comment: you're correct that `*(p+i)` is equivalent to `p[i]`. They are different syntax that express exactly the same thing and will compile to exactly the same assembly, namely, a _dereference_ of what `p` points to at the `i` offset. "Dereference" is the important part here. `p` is a pointer (a `char*`), and when you dereference it, the resulting object is what `p` points to, in this case a `char`. `char*` is not equivalent to `char`, and that's what the "makes pointer from integer without a cast" warning is about. Passing `p+i` will be the correct `char*` type (not saying that will fix everything).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably you're looking for:

```
void fun(char *p) {
    if (*p) {
        fun(p + 1);
        printf("%c", *p);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The program passes a `char` type to the function in the recursive case, while you'd want this to be a pointer. Iterating over a string given only a single character is not possible, we need to know *where* we are in the string.

As pointed out by various comments, using `static` is missing the point of writing a recursive function as it effectively introduces a global variable.
In fact, using an index variable is not necessary at all. You may simply use the pointer as an argument and parameter. Dereference it to obtain the character is currently points to, and increment it to make it point to the next character.

Corrected code, with a couple of improvements:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Declare the function before it is used.
// It doesn't return anything, so the return type should be "void".
void fun(char *p);

int main(void) // Correct main signature when not using command line arguments
{
    char *arr = "rama"; // We are not modifying the string, so a pointer to a string literal will do
    fun(arr);
    putchar('\n'); // Print a newline at the end of the program
}

void fun(char *p)
{
    if (*p == '\0') // Get the character the pointer currently points to
        return; // No need for an else if we return here

    fun(p + 1); // Pass the increment pointer
    putchar(*p); // Print the dereferenced pointer. No need for printf if we're just printing a single char
}
```

Another option is to make the function *tail-recursive*
(Inspired by a comment by Eugene Sh.). This requires an additional index parameter, but let's you print the final newline in de base case.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void fun(char *p, size_t idx);

int main(void)
{
    char *arr = "rama";
    fun(arr, strlen(arr) - 1);
}

void fun(char *p, size_t idx)
{
    // Happens in both the base case and recursive case
    putchar(p[idx]);

    // Base case
    if (idx == 0U)
    {
        putchar('\n');
        return;
    }

    // Recursive case
    fun(p, idx - 1);
}
```

Comment: You could add `putchar('\n')` in the base case condition inside `fun` to make it self-contained

Comment: @EugeneSh. This is not tail recursion. The program would print the newline _first_ and then the reversed string.

Comment: @EugeneSh. In any case, it gave me the idea of writing a tail-recursive version as well. Thank you!

Comment: @yun  surprisingly   when I replace  fun(p+1);  with  fun(p++);   the program does not print anything why so?   I though  p+1 is same as p++    isn't it?

Comment: @Ravi `p+1`, `++p` (pre-increment) and `p++` (post-increment) are all different things. The first one evaluates to exactly that, leaving `p` itself unchanged. The second one first increments `p` (like in `p = p + 1`) after which its result is used. The third one does what the second one does, but in reversed order, i.e. the expression takes the value of `p` first, `fun(p)` is executed and _afterwards_ `p` is incremented. In this case, `p` is never incremented in the recursion and the problem loops forever (or until stack overflow happens).

Comment: @Ravi p++ means p = p+1 , it increase the value inside p by 1. But p+1 does not overwrite the inner value.

Answer (score 0):

Your fun has return type int, but you are not returning any integer.
You have to declare function before main, as body of fun is below main.
fun have receiving type char * but you are sending char.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int fun(char *p);
int main(){
    char arr[]="rama";
    fun(arr);
}

int fun(char *p){
    static int i=0;
    if((p[i]) == '\0')
       return 0;
    fun((p+1));
    printf("%c", p[i]);
}
```